# Displaying information during loop

Tags: javascript

How can I display different information when loop is executing and when loop is finished?

In my example loop is testing single case every `100ms`. During this testing I wish to show information in `info.innerHTML` like `in progres`, but when loop is finished I wish show other information like "loop is done".

How to do it?

```
if (book.test(text) === true) {
    for (x = 0; x < table_first.length; x++) {
        (function (x) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (items[i] === fraze[x]) {
                    document.getElementById("" + x + "").innerHTML = fraze[x];
                    document.getElementById("" + x + "").className = "visible";
                    info.innerHTML = "";
                }
            }, x * 100);
        })(x)
    }
} else {
    info.innerHTML = "Nothing";
}
```

Comment: Use `setInterval` instead of loop of `setTimeout` calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if  `x` is the same size as the number you are testing against, it means it is the last element in the loop

```
if (book.test(text) === true) {
    for (x = 0; x < table_first.length; x++) {
        (function (x) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (items[i] === fraze[x]) {
                    document.getElementById("" + x + "").innerHTML = fraze[x];
                    document.getElementById("" + x + "").className = "visible";
                    info.innerHTML = "";
                }
                //check goes here
                if (x === (table_first.length - 1)) {
                    info.innerHTML = "All done!"
                }
            }, x * 100);
        })(x)
    }
} else {
    info.innerHTML = "Nothing";
}
```

By that you can know when to show the finish-text

Comment: Can you show me where I should add your part of code? I tested in different places and doesn't work. Newer was "All done".

Comment: I updated the answer for you. I realized i made a mistake when I tried to compare the x which starts at 0, with the .length counter that starts at 1

Comment: Doesn't work. Massage "All done" appears when the loop starts. :(

Comment: Right, updated it. But tell me, does the regular "load counter" thing work?

Comment: Is working. The regular "load counter" works too. Thank you very much.